# Slice of Writers vs pointers to Writers

Tags: go

This code results in a nil dereference:

```
tmpfile, _ := ioutil.TempFile("", "testing")
defer tmpfile.Close()
tmpwriter := bufio.NewWriter(tmpfile)
defer tmpwriter.Flush()
tmpwriter.WriteString("Hello World\n")
a := make([]*bufio.Writer, 1)
a = append(a, tmpwriter)
a[0].WriteString("It's Me") //Error here
```

This code results in no nil dereference, but doesn't actually write anything to the temp file:

```
tmpfile, _ := ioutil.TempFile("", "testing")
defer tmpfile.Close()
tmpwriter := bufio.NewWriter(tmpfile)
defer tmpwriter.Flush()
tmpwriter.WriteString("Hello World\n")
a := make([]bufio.Writer, 1)
a = append(a, *tmpwriter) //Dereferencing seems to cause the first string not to get written
a[0].WriteString("It's Me")
```

What principle am I missing here?  What's the idiomatic way to store a slice of writers, and what's going on under the hood to cause the nil in the first case, and what looks like a pointer dereference causing a side effect on the writer itself in the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a := make([]*bufio.Writer, 1)
a = append(a, tmpwriter)
```

then
len(a) == 2 and a[0] == nil, a[1] == tempwriter,
so

```
a[0].WriteString("It's Me")
```

panic with nil reference.

---

May be you need:

```
var a []*bufio.Writer
a = append(a, tmpwriter)
a[0].WriteString("It's Me")
```

or

```
a := []*bufio.Writer{tmpwriter}
a[0].WriteString("It's Me")
```

Comment: Or `make([]*bufio.Writer, 0, 1)`

Comment: Ugh, I misunderstood the semantics of make() - I assumed it just reserved the space to avoid reallocations, not surfaced a slice of that size.  The second form a la @32bitkid is what I was after.